# My catenation method isn't copying the new array to and old one

Tags: java, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to write a catenation that copies the parameter array into another array.  I am debugging my issue and am noticing that my arrays aren't copying to another one, and I dont understand how to access the elements in the arrays.  Every song has elements in them, these elements are Note[] data and are recorded with int manyItems.  What am i missing?

This is what I have:

The `Song` class:

```
class Song {
    private String name;
    private int bpm;
    private Note[] data;
    private int manyItems;
    private int currentIndex;

    public Song(String name, int bpm) {

        if (name == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("name is null");
        }
        if (bpm > MAX_BPM) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("bpm is greater than MAX_BPM");
        }
        if (bpm < MIN_BPM) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("bpm is less than MIN_BPM");
        }

        this.name = name;
        this.bpm = bpm;
        this.data = new Note[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    }
}
```

Concatenation method:

```
public static Song catenation(Song s1, Song s2){
    
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null) throw new NullPointerException("arguments are null");
    
    String newName = s1.getName() + " and " + s2.getName();
    int newBpm = s1.getBPM() + s2.getBPM();
    
    Song res = new Song(newName, newBpm / 2);
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Where is the constructor of Song?

Comment: You never pass the `Note[] data` from your `s1` or `s2` to your `res` (neither via the constructor nor via a setter). Is that what you are asking? Also, I assume you mean _concatenation_?

Comment: @CHANist sorry, i updated it

Comment: When you create a new Song, you did not update data, you just initialize it as an empty array ==

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  You want to know why something is not copying some array, but none of the code you have shown us copies an array.  `new Note[]` just allocates an array which will be initialized with `null`s.  It doesn't copy anything.  (There isn't even *anything to copy* at that point.)

Comment: Given your Song class, there is no way to do anything with the data attribute, it is private and has no getter or setters. And it is not passed via constructor.

Comment: On a side note: [Be wary of letting constructors throw exceptions](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/OBJ11-J.+Be+wary+of+letting+constructors+throw+exceptions).